# Stars in the sky

Tags: creation, young-earth-creation

Would Adam and Eve have been able to see a starry sky during the night? 
The nearest star is four light-years away, meaning it takes four years for light to reach Earth. 
Thus, the night sky must have been completely black, (except for the moon),
the first four years (give or take seven days) after the creation.

Or did God also create star-light that was already "on its way" towards Earth,
and if so, what would be the reason for this?

We can observe the Andromeda galaxy today, and the light from the stars takes over a million years to reach Earth. Thus, if Earth is significantly younger than that, it would mean that the light that we see now, must have been created "separately".

For me, this sounds like a big mystery.

Comment: This question isn't about Christianity. You might try asking the Space Exploration or Physics SE site if stars were visible at night  when the earth was thought to have been formed.

Comment: From a physics point of view, there is no question. I tagged the question "young-earth" since this issue only arise when earth was created 6000 years ago. Assuming the physicist point of view, the big bang was the cause of creating the universe, and this explains why we can see the Andromeda galaxy.

Comment: The Bible does say that God 'stretched out the heavens', we don't really know what that means and what effect it may have had on star light, but it is certainly an interesting phrase that may be interpreted to be broadly in line with inflationary cosmologies and perhaps a clue towards what happened.

Answer (score 0):

From a Southern Baptist standpoint we have no reason to believe that God being able to create light is unable to make it visible anywhere any time in his creation that he wants it to be. God not only created the Stars, he also created time, since there is no today. tomorrow, or yesterday let alone millions or Billions of years in Eternity.

We mere humans are constantly trying to limit God with our understanding of things, when in fact God is omniscient while we do not even know all about our surroundings.